# Remove previous data when executing AJAX request multiple times using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tui-calendar

I am using Toast tui calendar https://nhn.github.io/tui.calendar/latest/ and  I have an issue with ajax calling. It works correct except one thing, when I try to get data with the same option more than one times returns the new response but also still return the data of the previous response. please help me how can i resolve that thank u.

I think that there is something that I've missed.

**BookingController**

```
public function getBookingSlot(Request $request){

        $userBookings = Booking::where('room_id',$request->room_id)->where('booking_status',1)->get();
       foreach($userBookings as $booking){
            $events []  = [
                'id'            => $booking->id,
                'calendarId'    => $booking->id,
                'title'         => 'Booked',
                'category'      => 'time',
                'dueDateClass'  => '',
                'start'         => $booking->start_datetime,
                'end'           => $booking->end_datetime,
            ];
        }

            return  \Response::json([
                'events' => $events ?? null
            ]);
    }
```

**Html view**

```
                    <div class="card mb-5 ">
                      <div id="calendar" style="height: 800px;"></div>
                    </div>
```

**Script**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Calendar = tui.Calendar;
        var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
          defaultView: 'month',
          taskView: false,
          useCreationPopup: false,
          useDetailPopup: true,
          allDaySlot: false,
          droppable: false,
    
          template: {
            monthDayname: function(dayname) {
              return '<span class="calendar-week-dayname-name">' + dayname.label + '</span>';
            }
          }
        });
    
        document.getElementById('my-today-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
          calendar.today();
    
        });
        document.getElementById('my-next-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
          calendar.next();
        });
        document.getElementById('my-prev-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
          calendar.prev();
        });
        document.getElementById('weekView').addEventListener('click', function() {
          calendar.changeView('week', true);
        });
        document.getElementById('monthView').addEventListener('click', function() {
          calendar.changeView('month', true);
        });
    
        $(".butonSubmit").click(function(){
          let room_id = $(".carousel-item.active .room_id").val();
    
            $.ajax({
              url: "{{route('get-booking-slot')}}",
              type:"POST",
              data:{
              "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
              room_id:room_id,
              },
    
              success:function(response){
    
                calendar.createSchedules(
    
                 result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.events))
    
                );
                console.log(result);
              },
              error: function(response) {
              console.log(error);
            },
            });
            });
    
    
        calendar.on('beforeUpdateSchedule', function(event) {
        var schedule = event.schedule;
        var changes = event.changes;
    
        calendar.updateSchedule(schedule.id, schedule.calendarId, changes);
        });
```

Comment: If the server is returning old data then you need to fix that on the server (possibly the AJAX can help by sending some parameter to show which data it needs). But it's not clear if that's what is really happening, or whether you're simply adding a new Schedule to your calendar without removing the previous one, and therefore creating duplicate data. You gave quite a vague description of the problem without showing any sample data or expected results, or any debugging info to narrow it down. You also didn't show any server-side code or mention what calendar plugin you're using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it, having first read [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your problem. Once we have a clearer view of the exact situation, then we can probably help you a lot more. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson i have updated code please check. thank u

Comment: Thanks. So, it looks like the PHP code returns the same data every time (because it runs exactly the same database query every time), and you just keep adding that to the schedule without removing anything else. It's not 100% clear what you were intending it to do instead?

Comment: P.S. `result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.events))` is completely redundant...if you stringify something and then parse it, you just end up with exactly the same data you started with, because parsing is the reverse process of stringifying. You can just write `result = response.events` and the outcome will be the same.

Comment: Sir I have used this  result = response.events but unfortunately getting old data with new data please help me thanks.

Comment: `result = response.events` just fixed the specific json.parse redundancy that I mentioned. I never claimed it would solve your overall problem. I've explained to you what the problem is, but in order to fix it we need a clearer description of what you intend instead, and some sample data. I'll repeat: your SQL query just fetches all the records in the database every time. It does not filter them at all. So whatever you are deeming as "old" and "new" data, it knows nothing about that.

Comment: Maybe you just need to remove all the existing data from the calendar before you fetch all the records again. If you want to be more efficient, you'll need to send something to the server to tell it what the last record downloaded was, and then it can limit the query to only return records with a higher ID or timestamp, or something like that. It's difficult to be more specific in terms of a solution, because you have been fairly un-specific about the difficulty, and also haven't given any sample data etc. We do not magically know the contents of your database!